# IBM Notes 9 Social Edition - No Ascending Date Sort?

Tags: lotus-notes

Trying to customize my Inbox view. I want the default sort to be by ascending dates but the only choices in the "Customize..." dialogue are "None" and "Descending". Ideas?

Comment: HAve you tried clicking on "Descending" and seeing if it changes?

Answer (score 1):

In Notes 9 there is no need anymore to customize the sort oders... There is a new option in the mail preferences called "Automatically sort date columns". Just set the sort to your preference there.

On [this page](http://shrinilotustech.blogspot.de/2012/12/first-impression-with-notes-9-ibm.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ShriniLotusTech%20(ShriniLotusTech)) you can find more about the option: [image: Screenshot of Automatically sort date columns option]

Answer (score 0):

I have the preference set to automatically sort with the most recent on top, however that only works for the inbox.  It does not work for any email in folders or any emails that are archived.  Not sure why it doesn't work across the board.